# UIWindow not visible on top of Storyboard

Tags: uiwindow, uistoryboard

I have a UIWindow object that I have want to show on top a Storyboard. That I made like this -

```
UIWindow *webWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320,480)];
webWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert;
```

I am making it keyAndVisible like this -

```
[webWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The problem is that it's not visible. I tried NSLog to see all the Windows and it shows something like this -

```
Windows:(
    "<UIWindow: 0x9b5cf20; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x9b61400>>",
    "<UIWindow: 0x9846880; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x9846a60>>"
)
```

I read something about how window is used by Storyboard here - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006786-CH3-SW30

But its not clear how to use it to show a window on top of Storyboard.

Comment: Got it! Rather than making a new UIWindow object and adding a subview to had to make object of the app delegate like -`ExampleAppDelegate *myApp = (ExampleAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;`  And add subView like this - `[myApp.window addSubview:aWebView];`

Comment: please post that comment as an answer and accept it. Other people can find it useful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than making a new UIWindow object and adding a subview to had to make object of the app delegate like -ExampleAppDelegate *myApp = (ExampleAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate; And add subView like this - [myApp.window addSubview:aWebView];

Comment: Ok, you solved **your** problem, but didn't answer your **question**. Sometimes it's needed to add another *UIWindow* not *UIView*